# correspondence between muti cmakelists.txt file and vs project structure that created by cmake vs geneator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to build a visual studio c++ project under windows by cmake, there are two cmakelists.txt file in my source, and they are't parent-child relationship, main cmakelists.txt link library and add executable, the other one is only responsible for collating the dependent path to the global variable and passing to main cmakelists.txt file use.

At the beginning of executing cmake script, i pass the build dir path by command line parameter "-B".

Final i got the output file, but the structure of result direcotry puzzled me.Main-cmakelists.txt generate configuration file to build folder that was specified by earlier. But the other one cmakelists.txt, which generate configuration file outside, and one level heigher than specified build folder, and the folder with same name as the folder where sub-cmakelists.txt located.

I tried to find answer in offical documents and book like cmakecookbook, currently, no relevant entry found.

How can i specify the path for the generator ouput of sub-cmakelists.txt? I want to unify same build root folder for all cmakelists.

Is there have some professional tutorial introduction about correspondence between cmake file and vs project file?
**Thanks.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRVR5.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] as text not screenshots

Comment: I always get confused which files belong to which folder in this kind of display. It seems like the foldes structure is exactly as expected, assuming you're using `add_subdirectory(m_gl)`: The relative positions of the binary directories corresponding to the `CMakeLists.txt`s in the build tree remains the same as the directories in the source tree containing those files. This behaviour is described in [the documentation of the `add_library` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) What's the expected/desired build tree structure?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you mean by *"I want to unify same build root folder for all cmakelists."* btw? If you're trying to reuse the same binary for multiple source directories I'm afraid CMake will prevent this; you ***can*** make sure that the build results go to into a directory other than the current binary directory though, if this is what you're attempting to do. (If it is, please explain your rationale; there may be a different, possibly even a better solution to what you're attempting to accomplish.)

Comment: @AlanBirtles  thanks for your reply, i found the problem, because i ignore the syntax description of add_subdirectory(), the second parameter of commadn determine the directory of the sub-cmakelists output file

Comment: @fabin  thanks for your remind, i found the problem, because i ignore the syntax description of add_subdirectory(), the second parameter of commadn determine the directory of the sub-cmakelists output file, in the process of finding the answer, i directly skipped this part subconsciously, this resulted in no relevant content being found. It sounds very funny, but it really does happen to me. Indeed, my method of analyzing the problem is wrong.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of add_subdirectory() command, can specify the binary_dir path to place the output file for sub-cmakelist.